# update data in particular id and delete all other in single query.mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my website, I have an image table, where I store images of different products. I want to mark an Image as featured, so which will show at the front end. I give a radio button to mark it as featured. My problem is, if i already have an image as featured, and i want to update my field, how can i do the same with single query by add the new image as featured, and delete the old "featured" data.

i need something like this

```
update table set field=if id="1" then update to featured else update to non-featured
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table 
set field = case when id = 1 then 'featured' 
                             else 'non_featured'
            end
```

Comment: wow..thanks for the code..it works. Onw more help please. can i add where condition with this?? like "else 'non-featured' WHERE condition"

Comment: Yes. Instead of `else` use another `when ...`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
update your_table 
set field = if(id = 1 ,'featured','non_featured')
```